# How to fix Error CS1738 Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified

Tags: c#

```
public static Mutex CreateMutex(){
    MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
    MutexSecurity mutexSecurity = new MutexSecurity();
    mutexSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
    bool createdNew;
    return new Mutex(initiallyOwned: false,"Global\\E475CED9-78C4-44FC-A2A2-45E515A2436", out createdNew,mutexSecurity);
}
```

> Error CS1738 Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified

Comment: What do you think `Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified` means. Which is your named argument? Does it appear after all fixed arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So citing the C# Doc

> Named arguments, when used with positional arguments, are valid as long
>
> - as they're not followed by any positional arguments

So this is the cause, why you are running into the compile error.

When using C# 7.2 and later it says:

> Named arguments, when used with positional arguments, are valid as long
>
> - as they're used in the correct position.

---

*For more information see:
[Named and Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)*

---

So if we take a look at the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Mutex__ctor_System_Boolean_System_String_System_Boolean__System_Security_AccessControl_MutexSecurity_):

```
public Mutex (bool initiallyOwned,
              string name,
              out bool createdNew,
              System.Security.AccessControl.MutexSecurity mutexSecurity);
```

We will see that in your case the position is in the right order.
And if you would switch to C# 7.2 or later your code will compile.

But for lower Version, you have two options:

1. remove the argument naming for `initiallyOwned`
2. use named arguments for all arguments

like:

```
return new Mutex(initiallyOwned: false,
                 name: "Global\E475CED9-78C4-44FC-A2A2-45E515A2436",
                 createdNew: out createdNew,
                 mutexSecurity: mutexSecurity);
```

When using the second option the position of the named arguments does not matter anymore.

Comment: second option worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this issue recently. The affected code was compiled in CI with an MsBuild 15 (~VS 2017) instead of MsBuild 16 (~VS 2019) which the developers in turn use locally.

With the same language setting (automatically chosen due to Framework 4.7.2) this resulted in CS1738 error in CI.

I upgraded the used MsBuild in the CI step instead of changing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must place the named arguments (those with the [name] : [value] format) after those without the name specified. I don't know the constructor signature but the idea is to put the named args at the end, like:

```
public static Mutex CreateMutex() {
 MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
 MutexSecurity mutexSecurity = new MutexSecurity();
 mutexSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
 bool createdNew;
 return new Mutex( "Global\E475CED9-78C4-44FC-A2A2-45E515A2436", out createdNew, mutexSecurity, initiallyOwned: false,);
}
```